# Converting XML into HTML using XSL?

Tags: php, xslt

I have some XML, a XSL file and 4 CSS files. I am trying to process the XML using XSLTProcessor but it isn't working.

```
    $xml = new DomDocument;
    $xml->load('label.xml');

    $xsl = new DomDocument;
    $xsl->load('HTMLRestOfWorldRoutingLabelRendererOrig.xsl');

    $proc = new xsltprocessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
    $result = $proc->transformToXML($xml); 

    echo $result;
```

But this just displays the below without any sort of formatting.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>



            1
            1.11kg
            piece1
            1100123456782011641024001011
            123456782|123456782||1||John Smith|TNT Express|ATHERSTONE|CV9 1TT|GB|S||TNT Corporate Head Office|Neptunusstraat 41-63|AMSTERDAM|1011 AA|NL||EX|N|PR||||0|12.34|GBP|N|piecelinegoods desc|3|1.11|1.3676310000000003|N|18 Jan 2012|13:51:00


            2
            1.11kg
            piece1
            1100123456782021641024001011
            123456782|123456782||2||John Smith|TNT Express|ATHERSTONE|CV9 1TT|GB|S||TNT Corporate Head Office|Neptunusstraat 41-63|AMSTERDAM|1011 AA|NL||EX|N|PR||||0|12.34|GBP|N|piecelinegoods desc|3|1.11|1.3676310000000003|N|18 Jan 2012|13:51:00


            3
            1.11kg
            piece3
            1100123456782031641024001011
            123456782|123456782||3||John Smith|TNT Express|ATHERSTONE|CV9 1TT|GB|S||TNT Corporate Head Office|Neptunusstraat 41-63|AMSTERDAM|1011 AA|NL||EX|N|PR||||0|12.34|GBP|N|piecelinegoods desc|3|1.11|1.3676310000000003|N|18 Jan 2012|13:51:00


            123456782

                John Smith
                TNT Express
                TNT House
                ATHERSTONE
                Warks
                CV9 1TT
                GB


                TNT Corporate Head Office
                Neptunusstraat 41-63
                2132 JA Hoofddorp
                AMSTERDAM

                1011 AA
                NL


                100445
                GB

            3
            Express
            PR
            2012-01-18
            INT
            AIR
            C
            2


                CVT



                    EMA


                    LGG



                SP8
                19
                2012-01-19


            01

            GBP 12.34

            BSH
```

My label.xml is at http://pastebin.com/Shm09jCK

I have uploaded HTMLRestOfWorldRoutingLabelRendererOrig.xsl to http://pastebin.com/QPXE3B0r

I must be missing something obvious but this is new to me and I am not sure!

Comment: No errors from DomDocument class?

Comment: Hi, no, seems fine.

<pre>
<code>
$xml = new DomDocument;
if($xml->load('label.xml')) {
echo "Loaded OK";
} else {
echo "Loading failed";
}

$xsl = new DomDocument;
if($xsl->load('HTMLRestOfWorldRoutingLabelRendererOrig.xsl')) {
echo "Loaded OK";
} else {
echo "Loading failed";
}
</code>
</pre>

Shows "Loaded OK" both times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XSLT code there isn't any template that has a `match` attribute. This means that none of the templates are executed and the XSLT processor applies the **[built-in](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule)** (default) templates for every node type.

The net result from applying the built-in templates is that the output is a concatenation of all text nodes in the source XML document -- which is exactly what you get.

**Solution**:

Define at least one *matching* template such as `<xsl:template match="/">`. Within the code of this template you may call your named templates, though calling templates is generally a bad practice and applying templates should generally be preferred.

Comment: Interesting, this seems to almost be perfect. If I use <xsl:template match="/"> then I see one label but with the actual content missing, if I use <xsl:template match="labelResponse/"> then I see three labels but with the content missing. If I remove the ../ references throughout the XSL then I see three labels with the content correctly showing on the 2nd but not the 1st or 3rd.

I think this is enough for me to be getting on with now, I will try and figure out what is happening.

Thank you - you deserve one of these - http://i.imgur.com/58dmS.gif

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<xsl:output method="html" />`

Comment: I have tried adding this to the XSL file but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try this:

    $xml = new DomDocument;
    $xml->load('label.xml');

    $xsl = new SimpleXMLElement('HTMLRestOfWorldRoutingLabelRendererOrig.xsl');

    $proc = new xsltprocessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
    $result = $proc->transformToXML($xml); 

    echo $result;

Comment: Thank you for your help.

That gives me a PHP error:


Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /Users/chris/Dropbox/Sites/tnt/3/label.php on line 8

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: HTMLRestOfWorldRoutingLabelRendererOrig.xsl in /Users/chris/Dropbox/Sites/tnt/3/label.php on line 8

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /Users/chris/Dropbox/Sites/tnt/3/label.php on line 8

Comment: If I change the SimpleXMLElement line to:

$xsl = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('HTMLRestOfWorldRoutingLabelRendererOrig.xsl')); 

Then I get no errors but the output is the same as it was before - basically just the XML with all the tags stripped out

Comment: I tried this earlier, I get "SUCCESS, sample.xml was transformed by sample.xsl into the $result variable, the $result variable has the following contents" and then I see below exactly the same as the above example. Just the original XML with the tags stripped out!

Comment: Did you try another xml/xls/css?