# Issue with XML via XSL StyleSheet

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

I'm really hoping you can help here... When i transform the XML response against the XSL Stylesheet using XSLTProcessor transformToFragment it seems to be creating some data outside of the XML structure, right at the end:-

```
    123456782

        JohnSmith
        TNTExpress
        TNTHouse
        ATHERSTONE
        Warks
        CV91TT
        GB


        TNTCorporateHeadOffice
        Neptunusstraat41-63
        Taurusavenue111
        HOOFDDORP

        2132LS
        NL


        8783802
        GB

    3
    Express (ND)
    PR
    2016-11-15
    INT
    AIR

    2


        CVT



            EMA


            LGG
            8
            SP8



        SP8
        17
        2016-11-17


    63

    GBP 12.34

    BSH
```

I've included the XML, XSL and the result below, please could you take a look perhaps you've seen something like this happening before?

This online tool is useful for quick testing http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/

I cant see whats causing this data at the end to be generated, i'm assuming its something in the XSL template?

Thanks for any help whatsoever.

EDIT: it looks like someone had the same issue here but no actual specific answer [Converting XML into HTML using XSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911558/converting-xml-into-html-using-xsl)

Paul

XML Here:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<labelResponse>
    <consignment key="CON1">
        <pieceLabelData>
            <pieceNumber>1</pieceNumber>
            <weightDisplay code="1.11" renderInstructions="yes">1.11kg</weightDisplay>
            <pieceReference><![CDATA[piece1]]></pieceReference>
            <barcode symbology="128C">1100123456782011641424002132</barcode>
            <twoDBarcode symbology="pdf417"><![CDATA[123456782|123456782||1||JohnSmith|TNTExpress|ATHERSTONE|CV91TT|GB|S||TNTCorporateHeadOffice|Neptunusstraat41-63|HOOFDDORP|2132LS|NL||EX|N|PR||||0|12.34|GBP|N|||piecelinegoodsdesc|3|1.11|1.3676310000000003|N|15 Nov 2016|17:58:00]]></twoDBarcode>
        </pieceLabelData>
        <pieceLabelData>
            <pieceNumber>2</pieceNumber>
            <weightDisplay code="1.11" renderInstructions="yes">1.11kg</weightDisplay>
            <pieceReference><![CDATA[piece1]]></pieceReference>
            <barcode symbology="128C">1100123456782021641424002132</barcode>
            <twoDBarcode symbology="pdf417"><![CDATA[123456782|123456782||2||JohnSmith|TNTExpress|ATHERSTONE|CV91TT|GB|S||TNTCorporateHeadOffice|Neptunusstraat41-63|HOOFDDORP|2132LS|NL||EX|N|PR||||0|12.34|GBP|N|||piecelinegoodsdesc|3|1.11|1.3676310000000003|N|15 Nov 2016|17:58:00]]></twoDBarcode>
        </pieceLabelData>
        <pieceLabelData>
            <pieceNumber>3</pieceNumber>
            <weightDisplay code="1.11" renderInstructions="yes">1.11kg</weightDisplay>
            <pieceReference><![CDATA[piece3]]></pieceReference>
            <barcode symbology="128C">1100123456782031641424002132</barcode>
            <twoDBarcode symbology="pdf417"><![CDATA[123456782|123456782||3||JohnSmith|TNTExpress|ATHERSTONE|CV91TT|GB|S||TNTCorporateHeadOffice|Neptunusstraat41-63|HOOFDDORP|2132LS|NL||EX|N|PR||||0|12.34|GBP|N|||piecelinegoodsdesc|3|1.11|1.3676310000000003|N|15 Nov 2016|17:58:00]]></twoDBarcode>
        </pieceLabelData>
        <consignmentLabelData>
            <consignmentNumber>123456782</consignmentNumber>
            <sender>
                <name><![CDATA[JohnSmith]]></name>
                <addressLine1><![CDATA[TNTExpress]]></addressLine1>
                <addressLine2><![CDATA[TNTHouse]]></addressLine2>
                <town><![CDATA[ATHERSTONE]]></town>
                <province><![CDATA[Warks]]></province>
                <postcode><![CDATA[CV91TT]]></postcode>
                <country><![CDATA[GB]]></country>
            </sender>
            <delivery>
                <name><![CDATA[TNTCorporateHeadOffice]]></name>
                <addressLine1><![CDATA[Neptunusstraat41-63]]></addressLine1>
                <addressLine2><![CDATA[Taurusavenue111]]></addressLine2>
                <town><![CDATA[HOOFDDORP]]></town>
                <province><![CDATA[]]></province>
                <postcode><![CDATA[2132LS]]></postcode>
                <country><![CDATA[NL]]></country>
            </delivery>
            <account>
                <accountNumber>8783802</accountNumber>
                <accountCountry>GB</accountCountry>
            </account>
            <totalNumberOfPieces>3</totalNumberOfPieces>
            <product id="EX">Express (ND)</product>
            <option id="PR"><![CDATA[PR]]></option>
            <collectionDate>2016-11-15</collectionDate>
            <marketDisplay code="2" renderInstructions="yes"><![CDATA[INT]]></marketDisplay>
            <transportDisplay code="1" renderInstructions="yes"><![CDATA[AIR]]></transportDisplay>
            <freeCirculationDisplay code="" renderInstructions="no"/>
            <sortSplitText><![CDATA[2]]></sortSplitText>
            <xrayDisplay code="" renderInstructions="no"/>
            <originDepot>
                <depotCode>CVT</depotCode>
            </originDepot>
            <transitDepots>
                <transitDepot>
                    <depotCode>EMA</depotCode>
                </transitDepot>
                <sortDepot>
                    <depotCode>LGG</depotCode>
                    <sortCellIndicator code="" renderInstructions="yes">8</sortCellIndicator>
                    <sortLocationCode>SP8</sortLocationCode>
                </sortDepot>
            </transitDepots>
            <destinationDepot>
                <depotCode>SP8</depotCode>
                <dueDayOfMonth>17</dueDayOfMonth>
                <dueDate>2016-11-17</dueDate>
            </destinationDepot>
            <microzone code="" renderInstructions="no"/>
            <clusterCode>63</clusterCode>
            <legalComments/>
            <cashAmount code="12.34" renderInstructions="yes">GBP 12.34</cashAmount>
            <specialInstructions/>
            <bulkShipment code="Y" renderInstructions="yes">BSH</bulkShipment>
        </consignmentLabelData>
    </consignment>
</labelResponse>
```

XSL Here:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="RestOfWorldHtml" match="pieceLabelData">

<div id="box">

  <!--Logo-->
  <div id="logo">
    <img src='https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/rendering/images/logo_orig.jpg' alt='logo' id="tntLogo" />
  </div>

  <!--Market & Transport Type-->
  <div id="marketAndTransportType">
    <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/marketDisplay"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/transportDisplay"/>
  </div>

  <!--Hazardous-->
  <div id="hazardous">.
      <xsl:for-each select="../consignmentLabelData/option">
          <xsl:if test="@id='HZ'">
             <xsl:text>HAZARDOUS</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </div>

  <!--X-RAY-->
  <xsl:if test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/xrayDisplay)>0">
    <div id="xray">
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/xrayDisplay"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>

  <!--Free Circulation Display--> 
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/freeCirculationDisplay)>0">
      <div id="freeCirculationIndicator" style="background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;">
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/freeCirculationDisplay"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <div id="freeCirculationIndicator" style="background-color: #000000;color: #000000;">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <!--Sort Split Indicator-->
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/sortSplitText)>0">
        <div id="sortSplitIndicator">
            <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sortSplitText" />
        </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <div id="sortSplitIndicator">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <!--Consignment Number-->
  <div id="conNumber">
    <div id="conNumberHeader">Con No.</div>
    <div id="conNumberDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/consignmentNumber"/></div>
  </div>

  <!--Service-->
  <div id="service">
    <div id="serviceHeader">Service</div>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/product)>15">
            <span id="serviceDetail" style="font-size: 17px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/product" />
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span id="serviceDetail" style="font-size: 20px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/product" />
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </div>

  <!--Pieces-->
  <div id="piece">
    <div id="pieceHeader">
        Piece
    </div>

    <div id="pieceDetail"><xsl:value-of select="pieceNumber"/> of <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/totalNumberOfPieces"/></div>
  </div>

  <!--Weight-->
  <div id="weight">
    <div id="weightHeader">
        Weight
    </div>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="weightDisplay/@renderInstructions='highlighted'">
            <span id="weightDetailHighlighted">
                <xsl:value-of select="weightDisplay" />
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span id="weightDetail">
                <xsl:value-of select="weightDisplay" />
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </div>

  <!--Options-->
  <div id="option">
    <div id="optionHeader">Option</div>
    <xsl:variable name="numberOptions" select="count(../consignmentLabelData/option)" />    
        <xsl:choose>
            <!--If there are multiple options then display option id only-->
            <xsl:when test="$numberOptions >1">
              <xsl:for-each select="../consignmentLabelData/option">
                <div id="optionDetail">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                    <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
                </div>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <!--If there is only one option then display the option description-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/option)>0">
                      <div id="optionDetail">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/option" />
                      </div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <div id="optionDetail">
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>   
  </div>

  <!--Customer Reference & Account Number-->
  <div id="customerReference">
      <div id="customerReferenceHeader">Customer Reference</div>
      <div id="customerReferenceDetail"><xsl:value-of select="pieceReference" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="accountNumber">
      <span id="accountNumberHeader">S/R Account No</span>
      <span id="accountNumberDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/account/accountNumber" /></span>
  </div>

  <!--Origin Depot & Pickup Date-->
  <div id="originDepot">
    <span id="originDepotHeader">Origin</span>
    <span id="originDepotDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/originDepot/depotCode" /></span>
  </div>
  <div id="pickupDate">
    <div id="pickupDateHeader">Pickup Date</div>
    <div id="pickupDateDetail">
      <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">    
                <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="../consignmentLabelData/collectionDate"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--Origin Address & Delivery Address-->
  <div id="senderAddress">
      <div id="senderAddressHeader">Sender Address</div>
      <div id="senderAddressDetail">
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/name" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/addressLine1" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/addressLine2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/town" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>   
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/postcode"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/country"/>       
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="deliveryAddress">
      <div id="deliveryAddressHeader">Delivery Address</div>
      <div id="deliveryAddressDetail">
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/name" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/addressLine1" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/addressLine2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/town" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>   
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/postcode"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/country"/> 
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Route Details-->
  <div id="routing">
    <span id="routingHeader">Routing</span>
    <div id="routingDetail">

         <!-- Check if route includes any transit depots-->
         <xsl:if test="count(../consignmentLabelData/transitDepots/*)=0">
             <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="../consignmentLabelData/transitDepots/*">

            <xsl:if test="name(self::node()[position()])='transitDepot'">
                <xsl:value-of select="depotCode" />
                <br />
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="name(self::node()[position()])='actionDepot'">
                <xsl:value-of select="depotCode" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="actionDayOfWeek" />
                <br />
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="name(self::node()[position()])='sortDepot'">
                <xsl:value-of select="depotCode" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="sortCellIndicator" />
                <br />
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--Sort Details-->
  <div id="sort">
      <span id="sortHeader">Sort</span>
      <span id="sortDetail">
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/transitDepots/sortDepot/depotCode" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </span>
  </div>

  <!--Postcode/Cluster code-->
  <div id="postcodeHeader">Postcode /
      <br />
      Cluster Code
  </div>
  <div id="postcode">
    <xsl:choose>
    <!--If the length of the Cluster code is greater than 3 then the post code is being displayed
    instead, so different rendering applies-->
      <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/clusterCode)>3">
        <span id="postcodeDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/postcode"/></span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <span id="clustercodeDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/clusterCode"/></span>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </div>

  <!--Destination Depot-->
  <div id="destinationDepotHeader">
      Dest
      <br />
      Depot
  </div>
  <div id="destinationDepotDetail"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
      <xsl:when test="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/dueDayOfWeek/@renderInstructions='highlighted'">
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/depotCode"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/dueDayOfMonth"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/depotCode"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/dueDayOfMonth"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>   
    </xsl:choose>
  </div>

  <!--Barcode-->
  <xsl:variable name="barcode_url" select='"https://express.tnt.com/barbecue/barcode?type=Code128C&amp;height=140&amp;width=2&amp;data="' />
  <div id="barcode" name="barcode">
    <img>
       <xsl:attribute name="src">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat($barcode_url,barcode)" />
       </xsl:attribute> 
    </img>
  </div>
  <div id="barcodeLabel">
     <xsl:value-of select="barcode" />
  </div>
</div> 
<br style="page-break-before:always"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FormatDate">
    <!-- expected date format 2008 06 16 -->
    <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
    <!-- new date format 20 June 2007 -->
    <xsl:variable name="year">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DateTime,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="mo-temp">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($DateTime,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="mo">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($mo-temp,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="day">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($mo-temp,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$day" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '1' or $mo = '01'">Jan</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '2' or $mo = '02'">Feb</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '3' or $mo = '03'">Mar</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '4' or $mo = '04'">Apr</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '5' or $mo = '05'">May</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '6' or $mo = '06'">Jun</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '7' or $mo = '07'">Jul</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '8' or $mo = '08'">Aug</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '9' or $mo = '09'">Sep</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '10'">Oct</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '11'">Nov</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '12'">Dec</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result after transform:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <div id="box"><div id="logo"><img id="tntLogo" alt="logo" src="https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/rendering/images/logo_orig.jpg"/></div><div id="marketAndTransportType">INT/AIR</div><div id="hazardous">.
      </div><div style="background-color: #000000;color: #000000;" id="freeCirculationIndicator"> </div><div id="sortSplitIndicator">2</div><div id="conNumber"><div id="conNumberHeader">Con No.</div><div id="conNumberDetail">123456782</div></div><div id="service"><div id="serviceHeader">Service</div><span style="font-size: 20px;" id="serviceDetail">Express (ND)</span></div><div id="piece"><div id="pieceHeader">
        Piece
    </div><div id="pieceDetail">1 of 3</div></div><div id="weight"><div id="weightHeader">
        Weight
    </div><span id="weightDetail">1.11kg</span> </div><div id="option"><div id="optionHeader">Option</div><div id="optionDetail">PR</div></div><div id="customerReference"><div id="customerReferenceHeader">Customer Reference</div><div id="customerReferenceDetail">piece1</div></div><div id="accountNumber"><span id="accountNumberHeader">S/R Account No</span><span id="accountNumberDetail">8783802</span></div><div id="originDepot"><span id="originDepotHeader">Origin</span><span id="originDepotDetail">CVT</span></div><div id="pickupDate"><div id="pickupDateHeader">Pickup Date</div><div id="pickupDateDetail">15 Nov 2016</div></div><div id="senderAddress"><div id="senderAddressHeader">Sender Address</div><div id="senderAddressDetail">JohnSmith<br/>TNTExpress<br/>TNTHouse<br/>ATHERSTONE  CV91TT<br/>GB</div></div><div id="deliveryAddress"><div id="deliveryAddressHeader">Delivery Address</div><div id="deliveryAddressDetail">TNTCorporateHeadOffice<br/>Neptunusstraat41-63<br/>Taurusavenue111<br/>HOOFDDORP  2132LS<br/>NL</div></div><div id="routing"><span id="routingHeader">Routing</span><div id="routingDetail">EMA<br/>LGG-8<br/></div></div><div id="sort"><span id="sortHeader">Sort</span><span id="sortDetail">LGG </span></div><div id="postcodeHeader">Postcode /
      <br/>
      Cluster Code
  </div><div id="postcode"><span id="clustercodeDetail">63</span></div><div id="destinationDepotHeader">
      Dest
      <br/>
      Depot
  </div><div id="destinationDepotDetail">SP8-17</div><div name="barcode" id="barcode"><img src="https://express.tnt.com/barbecue/barcode?type=Code128C&amp;height=140&amp;width=2&amp;data=1100123456782011641424002132"/></div><div id="barcodeLabel">1100123456782011641424002132</div></div><br style="page-break-before:always"/>
        <div id="box"><div id="logo"><img id="tntLogo" alt="logo" src="https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/rendering/images/logo_orig.jpg"/></div><div id="marketAndTransportType">INT/AIR</div><div id="hazardous">.
      </div><div style="background-color: #000000;color: #000000;" id="freeCirculationIndicator"> </div><div id="sortSplitIndicator">2</div><div id="conNumber"><div id="conNumberHeader">Con No.</div><div id="conNumberDetail">123456782</div></div><div id="service"><div id="serviceHeader">Service</div><span style="font-size: 20px;" id="serviceDetail">Express (ND)</span></div><div id="piece"><div id="pieceHeader">
        Piece
    </div><div id="pieceDetail">2 of 3</div></div><div id="weight"><div id="weightHeader">
        Weight
    </div><span id="weightDetail">1.11kg</span> </div><div id="option"><div id="optionHeader">Option</div><div id="optionDetail">PR</div></div><div id="customerReference"><div id="customerReferenceHeader">Customer Reference</div><div id="customerReferenceDetail">piece1</div></div><div id="accountNumber"><span id="accountNumberHeader">S/R Account No</span><span id="accountNumberDetail">8783802</span></div><div id="originDepot"><span id="originDepotHeader">Origin</span><span id="originDepotDetail">CVT</span></div><div id="pickupDate"><div id="pickupDateHeader">Pickup Date</div><div id="pickupDateDetail">15 Nov 2016</div></div><div id="senderAddress"><div id="senderAddressHeader">Sender Address</div><div id="senderAddressDetail">JohnSmith<br/>TNTExpress<br/>TNTHouse<br/>ATHERSTONE  CV91TT<br/>GB</div></div><div id="deliveryAddress"><div id="deliveryAddressHeader">Delivery Address</div><div id="deliveryAddressDetail">TNTCorporateHeadOffice<br/>Neptunusstraat41-63<br/>Taurusavenue111<br/>HOOFDDORP  2132LS<br/>NL</div></div><div id="routing"><span id="routingHeader">Routing</span><div id="routingDetail">EMA<br/>LGG-8<br/></div></div><div id="sort"><span id="sortHeader">Sort</span><span id="sortDetail">LGG </span></div><div id="postcodeHeader">Postcode /
      <br/>
      Cluster Code
  </div><div id="postcode"><span id="clustercodeDetail">63</span></div><div id="destinationDepotHeader">
      Dest
      <br/>
      Depot
  </div><div id="destinationDepotDetail">SP8-17</div><div name="barcode" id="barcode"><img src="https://express.tnt.com/barbecue/barcode?type=Code128C&amp;height=140&amp;width=2&amp;data=1100123456782021641424002132"/></div><div id="barcodeLabel">1100123456782021641424002132</div></div><br style="page-break-before:always"/>
        <div id="box"><div id="logo"><img id="tntLogo" alt="logo" src="https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/rendering/images/logo_orig.jpg"/></div><div id="marketAndTransportType">INT/AIR</div><div id="hazardous">.
      </div><div style="background-color: #000000;color: #000000;" id="freeCirculationIndicator"> </div><div id="sortSplitIndicator">2</div><div id="conNumber"><div id="conNumberHeader">Con No.</div><div id="conNumberDetail">123456782</div></div><div id="service"><div id="serviceHeader">Service</div><span style="font-size: 20px;" id="serviceDetail">Express (ND)</span></div><div id="piece"><div id="pieceHeader">
        Piece
    </div><div id="pieceDetail">3 of 3</div></div><div id="weight"><div id="weightHeader">
        Weight
    </div><span id="weightDetail">1.11kg</span> </div><div id="option"><div id="optionHeader">Option</div><div id="optionDetail">PR</div></div><div id="customerReference"><div id="customerReferenceHeader">Customer Reference</div><div id="customerReferenceDetail">piece3</div></div><div id="accountNumber"><span id="accountNumberHeader">S/R Account No</span><span id="accountNumberDetail">8783802</span></div><div id="originDepot"><span id="originDepotHeader">Origin</span><span id="originDepotDetail">CVT</span></div><div id="pickupDate"><div id="pickupDateHeader">Pickup Date</div><div id="pickupDateDetail">15 Nov 2016</div></div><div id="senderAddress"><div id="senderAddressHeader">Sender Address</div><div id="senderAddressDetail">JohnSmith<br/>TNTExpress<br/>TNTHouse<br/>ATHERSTONE  CV91TT<br/>GB</div></div><div id="deliveryAddress"><div id="deliveryAddressHeader">Delivery Address</div><div id="deliveryAddressDetail">TNTCorporateHeadOffice<br/>Neptunusstraat41-63<br/>Taurusavenue111<br/>HOOFDDORP  2132LS<br/>NL</div></div><div id="routing"><span id="routingHeader">Routing</span><div id="routingDetail">EMA<br/>LGG-8<br/></div></div><div id="sort"><span id="sortHeader">Sort</span><span id="sortDetail">LGG </span></div><div id="postcodeHeader">Postcode /
      <br/>
      Cluster Code
  </div><div id="postcode"><span id="clustercodeDetail">63</span></div><div id="destinationDepotHeader">
      Dest
      <br/>
      Depot
  </div><div id="destinationDepotDetail">SP8-17</div><div name="barcode" id="barcode"><img src="https://express.tnt.com/barbecue/barcode?type=Code128C&amp;height=140&amp;width=2&amp;data=1100123456782031641424002132"/></div><div id="barcodeLabel">1100123456782031641424002132</div></div><br style="page-break-before:always"/>

            123456782

                JohnSmith
                TNTExpress
                TNTHouse
                ATHERSTONE
                Warks
                CV91TT
                GB


                TNTCorporateHeadOffice
                Neptunusstraat41-63
                Taurusavenue111
                HOOFDDORP

                2132LS
                NL


                8783802
                GB

            3
            Express (ND)
            PR
            2016-11-15
            INT
            AIR

            2


                CVT



                    EMA


                    LGG
                    8
                    SP8



                SP8
                17
                2016-11-17


            63

            GBP 12.34

            BSH
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have written a single matching template so the other elements are handled by the [built-in templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) which copy any text node children through to the result. Either add `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` to prevent that in general or at the entry point use `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="//pieceLabelData"/></xsl:template>`. I hope that suffices, you have posted that long snippets that I have not checked all code, so I think the diagnostic and explanation is fine, hopefully the suggested fix suffices as well.

So you need

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="RestOfWorldHtml" match="pieceLabelData">

<div id="box">

  <!--Logo-->
  <div id="logo">
    <img src='https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/rendering/images/logo_orig.jpg' alt='logo' id="tntLogo" />
  </div>

  <!--Market & Transport Type-->
  <div id="marketAndTransportType">
    <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/marketDisplay"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/transportDisplay"/>
  </div>

  <!--Hazardous-->
  <div id="hazardous">.
      <xsl:for-each select="../consignmentLabelData/option">
          <xsl:if test="@id='HZ'">
             <xsl:text>HAZARDOUS</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </div>

  <!--X-RAY-->
  <xsl:if test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/xrayDisplay)>0">
    <div id="xray">
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/xrayDisplay"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>

  <!--Free Circulation Display--> 
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/freeCirculationDisplay)>0">
      <div id="freeCirculationIndicator" style="background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;">
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/freeCirculationDisplay"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <div id="freeCirculationIndicator" style="background-color: #000000;color: #000000;">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <!--Sort Split Indicator-->
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/sortSplitText)>0">
        <div id="sortSplitIndicator">
            <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sortSplitText" />
        </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <div id="sortSplitIndicator">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <!--Consignment Number-->
  <div id="conNumber">
    <div id="conNumberHeader">Con No.</div>
    <div id="conNumberDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/consignmentNumber"/></div>
  </div>

  <!--Service-->
  <div id="service">
    <div id="serviceHeader">Service</div>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/product)>15">
            <span id="serviceDetail" style="font-size: 17px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/product" />
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span id="serviceDetail" style="font-size: 20px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/product" />
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </div>

  <!--Pieces-->
  <div id="piece">
    <div id="pieceHeader">
        Piece
    </div>

    <div id="pieceDetail"><xsl:value-of select="pieceNumber"/> of <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/totalNumberOfPieces"/></div>
  </div>

  <!--Weight-->
  <div id="weight">
    <div id="weightHeader">
        Weight
    </div>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="weightDisplay/@renderInstructions='highlighted'">
            <span id="weightDetailHighlighted">
                <xsl:value-of select="weightDisplay" />
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span id="weightDetail">
                <xsl:value-of select="weightDisplay" />
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </div>

  <!--Options-->
  <div id="option">
    <div id="optionHeader">Option</div>
    <xsl:variable name="numberOptions" select="count(../consignmentLabelData/option)" />    
        <xsl:choose>
            <!--If there are multiple options then display option id only-->
            <xsl:when test="$numberOptions >1">
              <xsl:for-each select="../consignmentLabelData/option">
                <div id="optionDetail">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                    <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
                </div>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <!--If there is only one option then display the option description-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/option)>0">
                      <div id="optionDetail">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/option" />
                      </div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <div id="optionDetail">
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>   
  </div>

  <!--Customer Reference & Account Number-->
  <div id="customerReference">
      <div id="customerReferenceHeader">Customer Reference</div>
      <div id="customerReferenceDetail"><xsl:value-of select="pieceReference" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="accountNumber">
      <span id="accountNumberHeader">S/R Account No</span>
      <span id="accountNumberDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/account/accountNumber" /></span>
  </div>

  <!--Origin Depot & Pickup Date-->
  <div id="originDepot">
    <span id="originDepotHeader">Origin</span>
    <span id="originDepotDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/originDepot/depotCode" /></span>
  </div>
  <div id="pickupDate">
    <div id="pickupDateHeader">Pickup Date</div>
    <div id="pickupDateDetail">
      <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">    
                <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="../consignmentLabelData/collectionDate"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--Origin Address & Delivery Address-->
  <div id="senderAddress">
      <div id="senderAddressHeader">Sender Address</div>
      <div id="senderAddressDetail">
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/name" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/addressLine1" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/addressLine2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/town" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>   
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/postcode"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/sender/country"/>       
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="deliveryAddress">
      <div id="deliveryAddressHeader">Delivery Address</div>
      <div id="deliveryAddressDetail">
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/name" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/addressLine1" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/addressLine2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/town" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>   
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/postcode"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/country"/> 
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Route Details-->
  <div id="routing">
    <span id="routingHeader">Routing</span>
    <div id="routingDetail">

         <!-- Check if route includes any transit depots-->
         <xsl:if test="count(../consignmentLabelData/transitDepots/*)=0">
             <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="../consignmentLabelData/transitDepots/*">

            <xsl:if test="name(self::node()[position()])='transitDepot'">
                <xsl:value-of select="depotCode" />
                <br />
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="name(self::node()[position()])='actionDepot'">
                <xsl:value-of select="depotCode" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="actionDayOfWeek" />
                <br />
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="name(self::node()[position()])='sortDepot'">
                <xsl:value-of select="depotCode" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="sortCellIndicator" />
                <br />
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--Sort Details-->
  <div id="sort">
      <span id="sortHeader">Sort</span>
      <span id="sortDetail">
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/transitDepots/sortDepot/depotCode" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </span>
  </div>

  <!--Postcode/Cluster code-->
  <div id="postcodeHeader">Postcode /
      <br />
      Cluster Code
  </div>
  <div id="postcode">
    <xsl:choose>
    <!--If the length of the Cluster code is greater than 3 then the post code is being displayed
    instead, so different rendering applies-->
      <xsl:when test="string-length(../consignmentLabelData/clusterCode)>3">
        <span id="postcodeDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/delivery/postcode"/></span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <span id="clustercodeDetail"><xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/clusterCode"/></span>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </div>

  <!--Destination Depot-->
  <div id="destinationDepotHeader">
      Dest
      <br />
      Depot
  </div>
  <div id="destinationDepotDetail"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
      <xsl:when test="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/dueDayOfWeek/@renderInstructions='highlighted'">
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/depotCode"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/dueDayOfMonth"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/depotCode"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/destinationDepot/dueDayOfMonth"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>   
    </xsl:choose>
  </div>

  <!--Barcode-->
  <xsl:variable name="barcode_url" select='"https://express.tnt.com/barbecue/barcode?type=Code128C&amp;height=140&amp;width=2&amp;data="' />
  <div id="barcode" name="barcode">
    <img>
       <xsl:attribute name="src">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat($barcode_url,barcode)" />
       </xsl:attribute> 
    </img>
  </div>
  <div id="barcodeLabel">
     <xsl:value-of select="barcode" />
  </div>
</div> 
<br style="page-break-before:always"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FormatDate">
    <!-- expected date format 2008 06 16 -->
    <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
    <!-- new date format 20 June 2007 -->
    <xsl:variable name="year">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DateTime,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="mo-temp">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($DateTime,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="mo">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($mo-temp,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="day">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($mo-temp,'-')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$day" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '1' or $mo = '01'">Jan</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '2' or $mo = '02'">Feb</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '3' or $mo = '03'">Mar</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '4' or $mo = '04'">Apr</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '5' or $mo = '05'">May</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '6' or $mo = '06'">Jun</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '7' or $mo = '07'">Jul</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '8' or $mo = '08'">Aug</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '9' or $mo = '09'">Sep</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '10'">Oct</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '11'">Nov</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mo = '12'">Dec</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=85366593-91a7-4c00-95ca-1677c2e9a84b-xsltransformation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  i've found an old topic here, looks like someone was having the exact same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911558/converting-xml-into-html-using-xsl  i think it is a problem with knowing what match="" criteria to use.  I still cant get it to produce 3 labels... :(

Comment: Start with adding `<xsl:output method="html"/>`, that can help when creating fragments of HTML in client-side script. If you still have problems then edit the question as to what you have now and where you are stuck, I think the problem about the unwanted content is solved.